# Check date is expired or not on Moment Date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date Format like this

```
[{"Exp_Date":"28-Feb-19"},{"Exp_Date":"30-Apr-19"},{"Exp_Date":"28-Jun-19"},{"Exp_Date":"29-Nov-19"}]
```

Now I have to check whether my Date is less that First value of array of objects. If less then I have to pick First object,

If that date expired then I have to use the next date.

I want to implement this on Moment.

I know the subtract of moment but that not solve my  purpose. Anyone can guide me how to solve this. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const a = [{ "Exp_Date": "28-Feb-19" }, { "Exp_Date": "30-Apr-19" }, { "Exp_Date": "28-Jun-19" }, { "Exp_Date": "29-Nov-19" }];
let i = 0;
while (a[i] && moment().isAfter(moment(a[i].Exp_Date, "DD-MMM-YY"))) {
    i++;
}
if (a[i]) {
    return a[i];
} else {
    return null;
}
```

You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4epxfmt6/)

Comment: I got the error i.e Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 28-Feb-19, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Comment: Maybe you use a wrong moment js version. Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/4epxfmt6/

Comment: Dear I Am on node. I dont know why this will generates an error. I checked thats its working fine jsfiddle

Comment: how if you change moment().isAfter(moment(a[i].Exp_Date))) to moment().isAfter(moment(a[i].Exp_Date, "DD-MMM-YY")))

Answer (score 0):

You could do this check in a loop:

```
var array = [{"exp_date":"28-Feb-19"},{"exp_date":"10-Feb-19"}];
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log(moment(new Date()).isAfter(moment(new Date(array[i]["exp_date"]))));
}
```

This uses `new Date()` objects which seem to be easier on moment

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [{ "Exp_Date": "28-Feb-19" }, { "Exp_Date": "30-Apr-19" }, { "Exp_Date": "28-Jun-19" }, { "Exp_Date": "29-Nov-19" }];
let i = 0;
while (a[i] && moment().isAfter(moment(a[i].Exp_Date),'DD-MMM-YY')) { // <-- change this
    i++;
}
if (a[i]) {
    return a[i];
} else {
    return null;
}
```

updated answer of Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know about `moment` but this could easily be done will js.

```js
var dates =[{"Exp_Date":"28-Feb-19"},{"Exp_Date":"30-Apr-19"},{"Exp_Date":"28-Jun-19"},{"Exp_Date":"29-Nov-19"}]

var d = new Date("01-march-19");
// sort the array first, this is optional, then find the current Exp_Date Index
var index = dates
 .sort((a,b)=> new Date(a.Exp_Date) - new Date(b.Exp_Date))
 .findIndex((item)=> new Date(item.Exp_Date) >= d);
 
console.log(dates[index])
```